# JMeter SMTP Sampler not triggering on Failure

Tags: jmeter

I have created a Thread Group and have 2 test sampler - Create Service and Create Project. I have added an SMTP Sampler to this Thread group and added an IF Controller with this script `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` But this SMTP Sampler is not triggering when I run the Thread group and there is a failure on Service Creation. what am I doing wrong here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Controller expects the "condition" to be `true` or `false`, what you put resolves into `!true` hence it doesn't fire.

I would suggest considering switching to [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3("${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}" == "false",)}
```

[image]

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)